# When was the last 'clean' race?

Tags: trivia, formula-1

When was the last 'clean' Formula 1 race?

A 'clean' race is one in which all cars that made a time in qualifications ended the full race (they did not retire or receive a DNF or DNS).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just as an update to the [previously accepted answer](https://sports.stackexchange.com/a/18524/16880), which is from 2018, the last *"clean"* race as OP describes was the **2019 Austrian GP**.

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2019_Austrian_Grand_Prix):

> Verstappen's victory marked the first win for a Honda-powered F1 car since Jenson Button in the 2006 Hungarian Grand Prix. The race was also the first race in the season not to be won by a Mercedes driver, as Valtteri Bottas finished in third and Lewis Hamilton fifth. Antonio Giovinazzi scored his first ever career points in Formula One by finishing tenth place.[13] **This also marked the first race in which every driver saw the chequered flag since the 2016 Japanese Grand Prix**. (emphasis mine)

Answer (score 6):

## As of June 2018: the 2016 Japanese Grand Prix

Prior to the 2016 Chinese Grand Prix, [only five races had finished with a full house](https://www.formula1.com/en/latest/features/2016/4/the-rare-occasions-every-car-was-a-finisher.html). That list includes the 2015 Japan Grand Prix, where Felipe Nasr did not physically finish the race, but was classified after having run more than 90% of the total distance.

The 2016 Chinese and subsequent 2016 Japanese Grands Prix both had a true full house finish, 22 of 22 cars that qualified also finished.

Since then, the closest to a full house finish has been a single retirement from a qualified field of 20 and of 22.